# C program to filter elements of type anyURI from string XML using XSLT

Tags: c, xslt, libxml2, libxslt

I have a XML string, I want to apply XSLT string on this XML to filter elements of type anyURI.

I am interested to use libxslt. But It transforms the xml present in file. I want to transform xml **string**.

How to write a C program to transform this xml string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of XSLT, libxslt is an XSLT 1.0 processor so it doesn't support W3C schema types like `xs:anyURI` in XSLT, you would need to use an XSLT 2 or 3 processor. Therefore I am not sure how you expect your XSLT program, whether you have it in a file or in a string, to filter out elements of type `xs:anyURI`.

In terms of C, I guess, depending on your "string" representation, you need to use http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlReadMemory or `xmlReadDoc` to get an http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlDocPtr for both the XML "string" input and the XSLT "string" input and then the libxslt APIs allow you to use http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/html/libxslt-xsltInternals.html#xsltParseStylesheetDoc to get an `xsltStylesheetPtr` and then to run `xsltApplyStylesheet`.